# I get wrong results when joining tables in node js with pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I have table called "ExternalCategories" when i send a LEFT JOIN query to the db using pg in node.js i get incomprehensible results

```
'SELECT * FROM "ExternalCategories" a Left JOIN "externalcat" b ON a."parentCategoryId"=b.id'
```

i get this :

```
    {
"id": 34,
"name": "Ordinateurs et Resea",
"img": null,
"views": 0,
"parentCategoryId": null
},
{
"id": null,
"name": null,
"img": null,
"views": null,
"parentCategoryId": null
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Vêtements",
"img": null,
"views": 0,
"parentCategoryId": null
},
{
"id": 34,
"name": "Ordinateurs et Resea",
"img": null,
"views": 0,
"parentCategoryId": null
},
```

but when i run the same query in Datagrip or pgAdmin4 i get correct data
[Results in datagrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdobJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think to distinguish returned columns name by aliases

```
'SELECT a.id AS a1,  a.name AS c2... FROM ExternalCategories a ....'
```